# How to extract a URL's domain name python (no imports)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently doing a school mini-project where we have to make a program to extract the domain name from a few given URL's, and put those which end in .uk (ie are websites from the united kingdom) in a list.

A couple of specifications:

- We cannot import any modules or anything.
- We can ignore urls that don't start with either "http://" or "https://"

I was originally just going to do:

```
uksites = []
file = open('urlfile.txt','r')
urllist = file.read().splitlines()
for url in urllist:
    if "http://" in url:
        domainstart = url.find("http://") + len("http://")
    elif "https://" in url:
        domainstart = url.find("https://") + len("https://")
    domainend = url.find("/", domainstart)
    if domainend >= 0:
        domain = url[domainstart:domainend]
    else:
        domain = url[domainstart:]
    if domain[-3:] = ".uk":
        uksites.append(url)
```

But then our professor warned us that not all domain names will be ended with a "/" (for example, one of the given ones in the test file we were supplied ends with ":")

Is this the only other valid character that can signify the end of a domain name? or are there even more?

If so how could I approach this?

The test file is pretty short, it contains a few "links" (some aren't real sites apparently):

```
http://google.com.au/
https://google.co.uk/
https://00.auga.com/shop/angel-haired-dress/
http://applesandoranges.co.uk:articles/best-seasonal-fruits-for-your-garden/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVbG35DeMto
http://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/
https://www.instagram.co.uk/posts/hjgjh42324/
```

Comment: Can you share the test file?

Comment: i edited it into the post, but the actual test of our project may be more extensive

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
def compute():
    ret = []
    hs = ['https:', 'http:']
    domains = ['uk']

    file = open('urlfile.txt','r')
    urllist = file.read().splitlines()
    for url in urllist:
        url_t = url.split('/')

        # \setminus {http*}
        if url_t[0] in hs:
            url_t = (url_t[2]).split('.')
        else:
            url_t = (url_t[0]).split('.')

        # get domain
        if ':' in url_t[-1]:
            url_t = (url_t[-1].split(':'))[0]
        else:
            url_t = url_t[-1]

        # verify it
        if url_t in domains:
            ret.append(url)

    return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(compute())
```

Answer (score -1):

Analyze the structure of the url first.
An url contains a few characters which cannot appear randomly e.g. the dot "."
The last dot allows therefore marks the end of the url + the country code.
The easiest solution could be to split the urls at the last dot with .rsplit(".", 1) and then take the first 2 letters after the split and re-attach them to the first part of the split. I chose a different approach and checked the second part after the split for alphanumeric characters, because after the country code there is always a special character (non-alphanumeric) so this allows for an additional split of the second part.

```
s = '''http://google.com.au/
https://google.co.uk/
https://00.auga.com/shop/angel-haired-dress/
http://applesandoranges.co.uk:articles/best-seasonal-fruits-for-your-garden/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVbG35DeMto
http://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/
https://www.instagram.co.uk/posts/hjgjh42324/'''

s_splitted = s.split("\n")

for raw_url in s_splitted:
    a,b = raw_url.rsplit(".", 1)
    c = "".join([x if x.isalnum() else " " for x in b ]).split(" ",1)[0]
    
    url = a+"."+c
    if url.endswith(".uk"):
        print(url)
```